# Filtering out multiple operating system versions from Get-ADComputer

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hey I am trying to run a script to get every computer at my works domain but I am having issues filtering out our servers. In this example I am trying just get computers with the operating system version 10.0 (10240) and version 10.0 (10586).

This is what I have.

```
$OSVersion = "10.0 (10240)", "10.0 (10586)"
Get-ADComputer -Filter ($_.OperatingSystem -eq $OSVersion)  -Property * | Select-object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-Csv 'C:\SomePath.csv'
```

But I am getting back

```
Get-ADComputer : Error parsing query: 'False' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.
At C:scriptPath:3 char:1
+ Get-ADComputer -Filter ($_.OperatingSystem -eq $OSVersion)  -Property ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: You can't use the `$_` variable in that context. Just use `OperatingSystem`. And I think you need to make it a string instead of an expression in parentheses.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer

Answer (score 1):

Or just do it this way...

```
Clear-Host;'6.3 (9600)','10.0 (14393)' | %{Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Where OperatingSystemVersion -EQ $_ | Select Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion}

Results ---

Name    OperatingSystem               OperatingSystemVersion
----         ---------------                 ----------------------
DC01    Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 (9600)            
...           
...            
...           
IIS01   Windows Server 2016 Datacenter  10.0 (14393)
```

Which I am assuming your were trying to do based on your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter and foreach

```
$OSVersion = @("10.0 (10240)", "10.0 (10586)")
Foreach($version in $OSVersion){
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -match $Version} -Property OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Select-object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-Csv 'C:\SomePath.csv'
}
```